# A simple example showing that IO doesn't satisfy the monad laws?

Tags: haskell, io, functional-programming, monads

I've seen mentioned that `IO` doesn't satisfy the monad laws, but I didn't find a simple example showing that. Anybody knows an example? Thanks.

**Edit:** As [ertes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12620418/1333025) and n.m. pointed out, using `seq` is a bit illegal as it can make any monad fail the laws (combined with `undefined`). Since `undefined` may be viewed as a non-terminating computation, it's perfectly fine to use it.

So the revised question is: **Anybody knows an example showing that `IO` fails to satisfy the monad laws, without using `seq`?** (Or perhaps a proof that `IO` does satisfy the laws if `seq` is not allowed?)

Comment: Couldn't you use IO to edit the memory of the running program via external means and force a law to be broken?

Comment: @KendallHopkins Good idea. Another idea (perhaps simpler) could be to exploit known problems of Haskell's lazy IO.

Comment: Is there a practical interest to show it without using `seq`?

Comment: @gawi The interest is mostly theoretical as any such example will very rarely occur in practical programming. The aim is to get detailed understanding of `IO`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

tl;dr upfront: `seq` is the only way.

Since the implementation of `IO` is not prescribed by the standard, we can only look at specific implementations. If we look at GHC's implementation, as it is available from the source (it might be that some of the behind-the-scenes special treatment of `IO` introduces violations of the monad laws, but I'm not aware of any such occurrence),

```
-- in GHC.Types (ghc-prim)
newtype IO a = IO (State# RealWorld -> (# State# RealWorld, a #))

-- in GHC.Base (base)
instance  Monad IO  where
    {-# INLINE return #-}
    {-# INLINE (>>)   #-}
    {-# INLINE (>>=)  #-}
    m >> k    = m >>= \ _ -> k
    return    = returnIO
    (>>=)     = bindIO
    fail s    = failIO s

returnIO :: a -> IO a
returnIO x = IO $ \ s -> (# s, x #)

bindIO :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
bindIO (IO m) k = IO $ \ s -> case m s of (# new_s, a #) -> unIO (k a) new_s

thenIO :: IO a -> IO b -> IO b
thenIO (IO m) k = IO $ \ s -> case m s of (# new_s, _ #) -> unIO k new_s

unIO :: IO a -> (State# RealWorld -> (# State# RealWorld, a #))
unIO (IO a) = a
```

it's implemented as a (strict) state monad. So any violation of the monad laws `IO` makes, is also made by `Control.Monad.State[.Strict]`.

Let's look at the monad laws and see what happens in `IO`:

```
return x >>= f ≡ f x:
return x >>= f = IO $ \s -> case (\t -> (# t, x #)) s of
                              (# new_s, a #) -> unIO (f a) new_s
               = IO $ \s -> case (# s, x #) of
                              (# new_s, a #) -> unIO (f a) new_s
               = IO $ \s -> unIO (f x) s
```

Ignoring the newtype wrapper, that means `return x >>= f` becomes `\s -> (f x) s`. The only way to (possibly) distinguish that from `f x` is `seq`. (And `seq` can only distinguish it if `f x ≡ undefined`.)

```
m >>= return ≡ m:
(IO k) >>= return = IO $ \s -> case k s of
                                 (# new_s, a #) -> unIO (return a) new_s
                  = IO $ \s -> case k s of
                                 (# new_s, a #) -> (\t -> (# t, a #)) new_s
                  = IO $ \s -> case k s of
                                 (# new_s, a #) -> (# new_s, a #)
                  = IO $ \s -> k s
```

ignoring the newtype wrapper again, `k` is replaced by `\s -> k s`, which again is only distinguishable by `seq`, and only if `k ≡ undefined`.

```
m >>= (\x -> g x >>= h) ≡ (m >>= g) >>= h:
(IO k) >>= (\x -> g x >>= h) = IO $ \s -> case k s of
                                            (# new_s, a #) -> unIO ((\x -> g x >>= h) a) new_s
                             = IO $ \s -> case k s of
                                            (# new_s, a #) -> unIO (g a >>= h) new_s
                             = IO $ \s -> case k s of
                                            (# new_s, a #) -> (\t -> case unIO (g a) t of
                                                                       (# new_t, b #) -> unIO (h b) new_t) new_s
                             = IO $ \s -> case k s of
                                            (# new_s, a #) -> case unIO (g a) new_s of
                                                                (# new_t, b #) -> unIO (h b) new_t
((IO k) >>= g) >>= h = IO $ \s -> case (\t -> case k t of
                                                (# new_s, a #) -> unIO (g a) new_s) s of
                                    (# new_t, b #) -> unIO (h b) new_t
                     = IO $ \s -> case (case k s of
                                          (# new_s, a #) -> unIO (g a) new_s) of
                                    (# new_t, b #) -> unIO (h b) new_t
```

Now, we generally have

```
case (case e of                    case e of
        pat1 -> ex1) of       ≡      pat1 -> case ex1 of
  pat2 -> ex2                                  pat2 -> ex2
```

per equation [3.17.3.(a)](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-610003.17.3) of the language report, so this law holds not only modulo `seq`.

Summarising, `IO` satisfies the monad laws, except for the fact that `seq` can distinguish `undefined` and `\s -> undefined s`. The same holds for `State[T]`, `Reader[T]`, `(->) a`, and any other monads wrapping a function type.

Comment: You forgot to include the link. Yes, it's an approximation, that's what the "behind-the-scenes special treatment" refers to. After GHC is done, it looks different, but as far as I know it's pretty much "as if".

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. Just one point: even though `IO` is modeled a state monad, it's only an approximation, like [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/163840/61231) describes. So if `IO` doesn't satisfy monad laws, it doesn't necessarily mean that `State` doesn't too.

Comment: The derivations above hold (mutatis mutandis) for the `State` monad (and `StateT`). For the others mentioned, more needs to be changed, but the point is that you can't define `(>>=)` and `return` for them without making them wrap a lambda (you can make the lambda implicit, `State k >>= f = State m where m s = ...`, but that still gives you a lambda), and `seq (\x -> y) z` is `z`, even if `y = undefined x`.

Comment: Regarding Russell's answer, I'm not sure I agree. `forever (putStrLn "Hello")` is a nonterminating computation, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I think the whole point of that proof is that nonterminating computations using `IO` can be very different (so the state monad isn't capable of describing them properly). This case is different and I think your proof is correct. I just mentioned Russell's answer to point out that reasoning about `IO` as if it were `State` might be tricky if one is not careful.

Answer (score 44):

All monads in Haskell are only monads if you exclude the weird `seq` combinator.  This is also true for `IO`.  Since `seq` is not actually a regular function but involves magic, you have to exclude it from checking the monad laws for the same reason you have to exclude `unsafePerformIO`.  Using `seq` you can prove all monads wrong, as follows.

In the Kleisli category the monad gives rise to, `return` is the identity morphism and `(<=<)` is composition.  So `return` must be an identity for `(<=<)`:

```
return <=< x = x
```

Using `seq` even Identity and Maybe fail to be monads:

```
seq (return <=< undefined :: a -> Identity b) () = ()
seq (undefined            :: a -> Identity b) () = undefined

seq (return <=< undefined :: a -> Maybe b) () = ()
seq (undefined            :: a -> Maybe b) () = undefined
```

Comment: I really wish you'd register for the site - it would be great to see all of your answers in one place!

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: You can see that [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/81110/please-register) if you want. At one point I went looking for possible duplicate accounts in the `[haskell]` tag and flagged some for merging when at least one was a registered account, but... :T

Comment: This is not quite true. In terms of the monad laws (which are defined in terms of `>>=`), the first expression is equivalent to `seq (\x -> undefined x :: a -> Identity b) ()` and not `seq (undefined :: a -> Identity b) ()`. I know that `(\x -> f x)` is equivalent to `f`, but this is not how GHC treats `undefined`s.

Comment: When I consider (return <=< undefined :: a -> Identity b) and (undefined :: a -> Identity b) I react differently but we don't say that means they're not the same morphism. Why would we worry about seq reacting differently? You didn't compose them with seq so you're outside of category theory already.

Answer (score 8):

One of the monad laws is that

```
m >>= return ≡ m
```

Let's try it out in GHCi:

```
Prelude> seq ( undefined >>= return :: IO () ) "hello, world"
"hello, world"

Prelude> seq ( undefined :: IO () ) "hello, world"
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

So `undefined >>= return` is not the same as `undefined`, therefore `IO` is not a monad. If we try the same thing for the `Maybe` monad, on the other hand:

```
Prelude> seq ( undefined >>= return :: Maybe () ) "hello, world"
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined

Prelude> seq ( undefined :: Maybe () ) "hello, world"
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

The two expressions are identical - so `Maybe` is not ruled out of being a monad by this example.

If anyone has an example that doesn't rely on the use of `seq` or `undefined` I would be interested to see it.

Comment: `undefined` is fine, but `seq` is an illegal alien in the Haskell-land. You can't have such function by the free theorem!

Comment: Try also `seq (putStrLn "goodbye cruel world") "hello world"`.

Comment: I really don't buy this as a reason for `IO` not obeying the monad laws; I _don't_ think `undefined` is fine. You can use undefined to prove that addition isn't commutative: `(error "first" + error "second") + 7` behaves differently to `(error "second" + error "first") + 7`. Shock! Haskell's addition isn't commutative! We would need an example that _doesn't_ use `undefined` or `error`.

Comment: (ghc's semantics in the presence of multiple exceptions is indeterminate choice - see the [docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/4.04/libraries/libs-6.html) for `tryall` as opposed to bag of exceptions in the original paper _A semantics for imprecise exceptions_ [ps](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/imprecise-exn.htm) [pdf](http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar_url?hl=en&q=http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.50.1525%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&sa=X&scisig=AAGBfm2wDRrEbgObjAXhjJ0cZ5pK5iDT7g&oi=scholarr&ei=5zZkUOyxLZKDhQfn-oAg&ved=0CBsQgAMoADAA) )

Comment: @AndrewC that relies on you distinguishing different bottoms, though. To the type system all bottoms look the same. I agree though, an example without undefined would be more satisfactory.

Comment: Keep in mind that `IO` *can* distinguish different bottoms, so such examples are entirely reasonable when considering `IO` specifically.

Comment: `( undefined >>= return :: IO () )` is *not* bottom.

Comment: @AndrewC Even without `undefined`, you could just use `let x = x in x` instead.

Comment: @PyRulez I in fact meant to exclude bottom rather than a specific error value. This is because ghc is explicitly non-deterministic with bottom, so non-determinism and law-breaking are unsurprisingly uninteresting here.

Comment: return <=< putStrLn "hello, world" is different to putStrLn "hello, world" anyway. They use memory, power and time differently which can trigger a reboot for a variety of reasons. Just because you didn't complete the computation before stopping doesn't mean the expressions aren't equal. You can have a deeply recursive equivalent which takes ages to compute and I can get bored and pull the power or kill the process - it's the same thing, the computation isn't complete but not because the expressions aren't equal.

Answer (score 4):

```
m >>= return ≡ m
```

is broken:

```
sequence_ $ take 100000 $ iterate (>>=return) (return ()) :: IO ()
```

clutters memory and increases computation time, while

```
sequence_ $ take 100000 $ iterate (>>=return) (return ()) :: Maybe ()
```

does not.

AFAIR there is a Monad Transformer which solves this problem; if I guess right, it is the Codensity Monad Transformer.

Comment: Interesting. But I believe it doesn't violate any laws, does it? I suppose there would be other monads for which the order of binding makes difference. Monad laws (or any other laws) don't prescribe how efficient the functions have to be. Thanks for mentioning the Codensity monad, looks worth exploring.

Comment: The point is, `(>>=)` on `IO` combines computations tree-like, while `(>>=)` on `Maybe` combines and reduces two Maybes to one Maybe. This difference causes all those already mentioned effects with `undefined` and `seq`.