# Why is seq bad?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

Haskell has a magical function named `seq`, which takes an argument of any type and reduces it to *Weak Head Normal Form* (WHNF).

I've read a couple of sources [not that I can remember who they were *now*...] which claim that "polymorphic `seq` is bad". In what way are they "bad"?

Similarly, there is the `rnf` function, which reduces an argument to *Normal Form* (NF). But *this* is a class method; it does not work for arbitrary types. It seems "obvious" to me that one could alter the language spec to provide this as a built-in primitive, similar to `seq`. This, presumably, would be "even more bad" than just having `seq`. In what way is this so?

Finally, somebody suggested that giving `seq`, `rnf`, `par` and similars the same type as the `id` function, rather than the `const` function as it is now, would be an improvement. How so?

Comment: The `seq` function is not lambda definable (i.r., cannot be defined in the lambda-calculus), which means that that all the results from lambda calculus can no longer be trusted when we have `seq`.

Comment: So `seq`, like `IO`, [has an implementation but no denotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439025/what-is-so-special-about-monads/16444789#16444789) (at least as a term in the lambda calculus). To salvage that lost trust, would both `seq` and `IO` need to be banished from Haskell?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

As far as I know a polymorphic `seq` function is bad because it weakens free theorems or, in other words, some equalities that are valid without `seq` are no longer valid with `seq`. For example, the equality

```
map g (f xs) = f (map g xs)
```

holds for all functions `g :: tau -> tau'`, all lists `xs :: [tau]` and all polymorphic functions `f :: [a] -> [a]`. Basically, this equality states that `f` can only reorder the elements of its argument list or drop or duplicate elements but cannot invent new elements.

To be honest, it can invent elements as it could "insert" a non-terminating computation/run-time error into the lists, as the type of an error is polymorphic. That is, this equality already breaks in a programming language like Haskell without `seq`. The following function definitions provide a counter example to the equation. Basically, on the left hand side `g` "hides" the error.

```
g _ = True
f _ = [undefined]
```

In order to fix the equation, `g` has to be strict, that is, it has to map an error to an error. In this case, the equality holds again.

If you add a polymorphic `seq` operator, the equation breaks again, for example, the following instantiation is a counter example.

```
g True = True
f (x:y:_) = [seq x y]
```

If we consider the list `xs = [False, True]`, we have

```
map g (f [False, True]) = map g [True] = [True]
```

but, on the other hand

```
f (map g [False, True]) = f [undefined, True] = [undefined]
```

That is, you can use `seq` to make the element of a certain position of the list depend on the definedness of another element in the list. The equality holds again if `g` is total. If you are intereseted in free theorems check out the [free theorem generator](https://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~sad/FreeTheorems/cgi-bin/free-theorems-webui.cgi), which allows you to specify whether you are considering a language with errors or even a language with `seq`. Although, this might seem to be of less practical relevance, `seq` breaks some transformations that are used to improve the performence of functional programs, for example, `foldr`/`build` fusion fails in the presence of `seq`. If you are intereseted in more details about free theorems in the presence of `seq`, take a look into [Free Theorems in the Presence of seq](http://www.janis-voigtlaender.eu/papers/FreeTheoremsInThePresenceOfSeq.pdf).

As far as I know it had been known that a polymorphic `seq` breaks certain transformations, when it was added to the language. However, the althernatives have disadvantages as well. If you add a type class based `seq`, you might have to add lots of type class constraints to your program, if you add a `seq` somewhere deep down. Furthermore, it had not been a choice to omit `seq` as it had already been known that there are space leaks that can be fixed using `seq`.

Finally, I might miss something, but I don't see how a `seq` operator of type `a -> a` would work. The clue of `seq` is that it evaluates an expression to head normal form, if another expression is evaluated to head normal form. If `seq` has type `a -> a` there is no way of making the evaluation of one expression depend on the evaluation of another expression.

Comment: `map g (f xs) = f (map g xs)` Uhh... Even in a total language with no `undefined` or `seq` that does not hold. `f = map (1 :)` `g = (2 :)` `xs = [[3], [4]]` involves nothing fancy at all but it absolutely does break that equality. Am I missing something really obvious or is basically this entire answer deeply flawed?

Comment: @semicolon The theorem is taking about polymorphic `f`, which couldn't invent new elements because it doesn't know what type it's operating on. Your `f` needs at least a `Num` constraint, it can't be `[a] -> [a]`.

Comment: @Ben Ah ok, my bad, that makes sense.

Answer (score 11):

Another counterexample is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12620418/1333025) - monads fail to satisfy monad laws with `seq` and `undefined`. And since `undefined` cannot be avoided in a Turing-complete language, the one to blame is `seq`.

Answer (score 2):

The angst about `Prelude.seq` (frequently in association with `⊥`) is mostly attributed to a few reasons:

1. it weakens *extensionality*

   ```
    -- (\ x -> f x) == f

   seq (\ x -> ⊥ x) y = y

   seq ⊥ y = ⊥
   ```
2. it weakens *parametricity*

   ```
    --  foldr k z (build g) == g k z

   foldr ⊥ 0 (build seq) = foldr ⊥ 0 (seq (:) [])
                         = foldr ⊥ 0 []
                         = 0

   seq ⊥ 0 = ⊥
   ```
3. it invalidates various laws e.g. those for the monadic interface

   ```
    --  m >>= return == m

   seq (⊥ >>= return :: State s a) True = True

   seq (⊥ :: State s a) True = ⊥
   ```

However:

1. Extensionality is also weakened by the combination of call-by-need semantics and the use of weak-head normal form, [as noted by](https://www.pauldownen.com/publications/first-class-call-stacks.pdf) Philip Johnson-Freyd, Paul Downen and Zena Ariola.
2. Parametricity is similarly weakened by the combination of GADTs and the corresponding map functions satisfying the functor laws, [as shown by](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.03389v3) Patricia Johann, Enrico Ghiorzi, and Daniel Jeffries.
3. The presence of the polymorphic fixed-point operator:

   ```
   yet :: (a -> a) -> a
   yet f = f (yet f)
   ```

   also imposes restrictions on parametricity, [as specified by](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/99370.99404) Philip Wadler.
4. Deriving laws for arbitrary recursive algorithms also requires strictness to be  considered, [as elaborated by](https://ris.utwente.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/284115323/thesis_M_Fokkinga.pdf) Maarten Fokkinga (see chapter 6).
5. That certain combinations of operators and values can invalidate basic logical or mathematical rules isn't new e.g. division and zero. Like division, [selective strictness](https://www.janis-voigtlaender.eu/papers/TamingSelectiveStrictness.pdf) is necessary - algorithms for determining strictness (a nontrivial property) are subject to [Rice's theorem](http://kilby.stanford.edu/%7Ervg/154/handouts/Rice.html): they may not always succeed, resulting in unexpectedly-excessive memory usage (i.e. space leaks) in programs. As for the choice to use primitive operators or annotations (for [patterns](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/bang-patterns.html) or [types](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html)), that usually doesn't change the adverse impact on important theorems and laws.

   Another option could be to use an [augmented form](https://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/%7Epszgmh/clairvoyant.pdf) of call-by-value semantics, but that presumes the method of augmentation being used is sufficiently *"well-behaved"*.

---

At some time in the future, perhaps there will be one or more advances in the computing sciences that resolve the matter. Until then, the most practical option is to manage the awkward interaction between useful laws and theorems and this along with other [real-world programming features](https://d-nb.info/1045276316/34).

Comment: Why `yet`? Think of the question every parent  travelling with children knows all too well: _are we there yet?_