# Is `evaluate` safe compared to `seq`?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, seq

As [shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12620418/1333025), `seq` combined with `undefined` does very strange things when it comes to equational reasoning, for example it can make any monad fail. Another example is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12687392/1333025).

Recently I stumbled upon [`evaluate :: a -> IO a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:evaluate) that does a similar thing - it evaluates its argument to WHNF but only when the `IO` action is evaluated. This seems to be much safer, as one expects that "in `IO` we can do everything". Of course it cannot be used everywhere, but often the need to evaluate an expression is connected somehow with an `IO` operation (like to force a producing thread to evaluate a computation instead of a consuming thread when working with `MVar`s).

So I'd like to ask, how safe is `evaluate`? Is it possible to create examples (involve `IO` of course) where it breaks reasoning about code like `seq` does? Or can I consider it as a safe replacement of `seq` (if it's possible for a particular program)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you still get the same issues caused by the `seq` command, in that any monad used in the first argument of `evaluate` will have its monad rules broken. Basing it off the rule in ertes's answer:

> In the Kleisli category the monad gives rise to `return` is the
>   identity morphism and `(<=<)` is composition.  So `return` must be an
>   identity for `(<=<)`:
>
> ```
> return <=< x = x
> ```

This means you should be able to replace `return <=< x` with `x` with any valid monad without changing the operation of the program.

Using that with the `evaluate` function...

```
evaluate (return <=< undefined :: a -> Identity b) >> putStrLn "hello"
```

outputs hello. Using what should be an equivalent statement by replacing `return <=< undefined` with `undefined`:

```
evaluate (undefined :: a -> Identity b) >> putStrLn "hello"
```

instead causes an `Prelude.undefined` exception.

This only happens with the evaluate function. Notice that `return` has exactly the same type signature as `evaluate`. If you replace `evaluate` with `return` in the above commands, the resulting action for both commands is the same (they output `hello`).